# overflow-x not working for content wrapped in td

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to allow allow content that's wider than the screen/viewport to overflow horizontally, without disturbing the rest of the page structure? Specifically, when my content is all wrapped inside a `table>tbody>tr>td`?

The concept works in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEn9/), where you see that everything is structured nicely on the page in a vertical manner, and the user can scroll horizontally in the very wide table.

However, the same concept breaks down in [this other fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQEn9/2/), where the screen/viewport blows up and attempts to accommodate full width of the very wide table. This is *undesirable*.

In my final implementation, I cannot pull my content out of the outermost `table>tbody>tr>td`, because that is beyond my control (I'm creating custom pages within Salesforce).

I'd prefer to avoid JavaScript if at all possible, but if that's the only option I'm open to suggestions. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't replace your tables with `div` elements, you could make the appropriate elements `display: block` to display like `div`s:

http://jsfiddle.net/yQEn9/3/

```
.div{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, James. I could've sworn I already tried that, but your proof is sitting very obviously there. Unfortunately for me, the strategy doens't seem to be working in Salesforce.

Comment: In Salesforce, using Chrome Developer Tools (for a proof of concept) I added the "div" class to the wrapping `table>tbody>tr>td` and then styled the "div" class as you suggested. I verified that Chrome reports that the computed **display** attribute is indeed set to "block", but the entire content area still bleeds over to the right. :-(